# Can type information be encoded in the untyped lambda calculus?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, typing, type-checking

I'm going to take the few pieces of knowledge I have about lambda calculi and ask a pair of very uninformed questions :-)

Is it possible to "embed" the corners of the lambda cube within the untyped lambda calculus?

It would seem that this might lead to a language where the programmer implements the type system in the language, rather than having it already implemented in the compiler.  Also, maybe the concept of type system could be generalized to "any arbitrary compile-time or run-time constraint checking".  Does such a language already exist?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. You can take typed $\lambda$-calculus of any kind and just delete the types. That "embeds" it into the untyped $\lambda$-calculus. But you must be talking about something else. What exactly?

Comment: I may be totally wrong but doesn't typed lambda calculus implement the type system in the language of untyped lambda calculus, and it is the use of syntactic sugar which makes typed language calculus look like a new language. My understanding is that typed lambda calculus can be implemented from just untyped lambda calculus.

Comment: @AndrejBauer Hmm, perhaps I am confusing the type system in a lambda with a particular implementation of it (within a programming language) that performs type checking.  I mean to express the constraints that a type system implies using the untyped lambda calculus.  From Guy Coder's comment, maybe this is already the case and I just didn't realize it.

Comment: @GuyCoder Interesting, you may very well be right- I don't understand enough to say either way.  Do you mean that type information is encoded in untyped lambda terms in a similar way to Church numerals, etc? (That would relate it to something I understand.)

Comment: I was hoping that @AndrejBauer would comment on my comment otherwise I will have to make is a new separate question. With regards to your statement, I believe so. Take a look at "An Introduction To Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus by Greg Michaelson" which I added as link to the Lambda Calculus [tag](http://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/lambda-calculus/info). It will take you some reading to understand, but it should have enough detail to answer your question.

Comment: @GuyCoder thanks for the reference!  I've only skimmed the first few sections so far, but looks like just what I was after.

Comment: You might also want to take a look at Chapter 10 "An ML Implementation of Simple Types" in ["Types and Programming Languages"](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/47705787) by Benjamin C. Pierce. Also check out Andrej's [The Programming Language Zoo](http://andrej.com/plzoo/)

Comment: Lambda calculi of various forms are *formal systems*. They consist of abstract syntax (for terms and for types, if present), judgments (typing judgments and equations), and rules of inference. They are not programming languages (unless we prescribe operational semantics) and neither is it the case that a type system equals a program that checks types. So I think this whole question is a bit misdirected, still. Of course, an important aspect of a type system is how to *implement* it on a computer, which brings in questions about algorithms, etc. But a priori, the type system has none of that.

Comment: @AndrejBauer I was a bit lost on part of your comment so I posted a new [question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19789/268), as it would be off topic for this question. Your help is always appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the comments, it is possible to reduce simply typed lambda calculus to untyped lambda calculus. This is the approach associated with Alonzo Church, called "Church Types" or "intrinsic types". Here, types are embedded in the language, and are intrinsic to the language. Still, the language can be stripped of it's types.

However, it is also possible to construct simply typed lambda calculus from untyped lambda calculus. This approach is associated with Haskell Curry, called "Curry Types" or "extrinsic types". Here, types can be derived from the AST of the language.

The latter type is what you are looking for. A thorough overview of the subject is [here](http://www.lispcast.com/church-vs-curry-types)